# Does Piccaso.into method, perofms scaling after loading the image according to ImageView scaleType attribute?

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I'm working with Picasso to download/load image into an ImageView
I can't understand if *into* method, perform scaling according to *scaleType* and *asjustViewBounds*
For the following code, does both attributes are being considered by Picasso methods?

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPeople"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/temproary_pic"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewToExamine"
    />

Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(android.R.drawable.temproary_pic).
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
    ...
    }
```

if i run the following code on the *onSucess*

```
  BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ((holder.imageView.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
```

i'm getting the bitmap with the exactly the resolution as in the url

Comment: Picasso does not scale anything, it simply set your ImageView's src to the desired image so all the scaling is done by the ImageView component.

Comment: @AnisBrachemi, thanks. So after setting the src, the ImageView passing the same procedure as when we set the src via android:src?

Comment: Yes exactly, unless you use specific picasso methods such as fit(), centerCrop() or centerInside() which will apply cropping but once again unrelated to your ImageView.

Comment: @AnisBrachemi, so according to what it will make the fit(), centerCrop, centerInside, etc.. ?

Comment: Those will be applied to the image's bitmap itself according to your ImageView size, you can learn more [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: @AnisBrachemi, thanks for the link . But from the link it can't be understand, if i will use lets say *cenrerCrop* method of Picasso, and also in my ImageView i defined the srcType as *centerCrop* isn't it redundant? will it cause the crop to run twice (one  time because of the method and the second time because if the *srcType* attribute in the xml? In addition, if i'm using centerCrop method of Picasso, will it consider *adjustViewBound* value? the crop is totally different when the attribute is set to true (and not false)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223789/discussion-between-anis-brachemi-and-eitanos30).